# z.Repeat.Once not working

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mocks to write my Unit Tests and I'd like to use `Assert.WasCalled` functionality, but I'm keep getting an error.

My help method used by a bunch of tests:

```
Private Function CreateSecurityTicketHelper(userName As String, validFrom As DateTime, validTo As DateTime) As ISecurityTicket
    ' Prepare a mock object for ITicketingDataManager interface
    Dim dataManagerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock(Of ITicketingDataManager)()
    ' Prepare a mock function for ITicketingDataManager.InitializeNewTicket(string, string)
    Dim returnSecurityTicket As Func(Of String, String, ISecurityTicket) = Function(u, k) New SecurityTicketEntity() With {.UserName = u, .Key = k}
    dataManagerMock.Stub(Function(x) x.InitializeNewTicket(Nothing, Nothing)).IgnoreArguments().Do(returnSecurityTicket)

    ' Create new TicketingManager instance
    Dim ticketingManager = New TicketingManager(dataManagerMock)
    ' Try creating new security ticket
    Dim ticket = ticketingManager.CreateSecurityTicket(userName, validFrom, validTo)

    ' Check if proper ITicketingDataManager method was invoked
    dataManagerMock.AssertWasCalled(Sub(x) x.InitializeNewTicket(Nothing, Nothing), Sub(z) z.Repeat.Once())

    ' Return the ticket
    Return ticketingManager.CreateSecurityTicket(userName, validFrom, validTo)
End Function
```

I can debug that method and all goes right until `AssertWasCalled` method is called, when I'm getting following exception:

> Test method
>   Authentication.UnitTests.TicketingManagerTests.CreateSecurityTicket_ValidUserNameAndKey_TicketIsCreated
>   threw exception: 
>   Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException:
>   ITicketingDataManager.InitializeNewTicket(null, null); Expected #1,
>   Actual #0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion says that `InitializeNewTicket()` method should be called once with arguments `(Nothing, Nothing)`.

If this method is being called with **some another** arguments then assertion fails.

You have to rewrite assertion to either A) accept **any arguments** or B) specify **correct arguments**.

See examples below.
Few notes about examples:
1. Ufortunatelly I'm not good in VB syntax so providing examples in C#.
2. It is not mentioned in question which parameters type has method `InitializeNewTicket()` so for example I assume it has `String` parameters.

To accept any parameters in assertion:

```
dataManagerMock.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.InitializeNewTicket(Arg<String>.Is.Anything, Arg<String>.Is.Anything),
    z => z.Repeat.Once());
```

To specify expected arguments (e.g. `expected1, expected2`):

```
dataManagerMock.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.InitializeNewTicket(Arg<String>.Is.Equal(expected1), Arg<String>.Is.Equal(expected2)),
    z => z.Repeat.Once());
```

Hope that explains the reason of your issue and helps to solve :).